# How to make junit testing to stop after first failing test

Tags: java, testing, tdd, junit

Is there a way to make running junit test to stop after a test fails?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I've been thinking about it for a while. The thing that keeps coming to my mind is: Why do you want that?

Comment: Exactly: why not see all failing tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes ... this ability (or the lack of it) is built into the various TestRunners (Console, AWT, Swing, Ant, Maven or the one built into Eclipse, etc).  You'll have to look for this control in the documentation for the specific platform you're using.

Comment: maven-surefire-plugin now supports a neat option, [skip after failure](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skip-after-failure.html)

Comment: Here is a POM example for maven's skipAfterFailure:   
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipAfterFailureCount>1</skipAfterFailureCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

Answer (score 5):

I know that in Ant, the junit task has options "haltonerror" and "haltonfailure" that controls this behavior.